# Can't extract var from firebase reading method

Tags: swift, firebase

How can I get the `numberOfMarkers` out of the reading method of Firebase in Swift? 
if I use the function in the `{}` this will save and I will be can use it not in the `{}`?

```
docRef = Firestore.firestore().document("Markol/Markers")
docRef.getDocument{ (docSnapshot, error) in
    guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else {return}
    let myData = docSnapshot.data()
    let numberOfMarkers = myData?["NumberofMarkers"] as? Int ?? 0
}
//Here i want to get the let numberOfMarkers


    var markerArrayList = [GMSMarker]()
    func makeAMarker(_ Latitude:Double , _ Longitude:Double , _ Title:String,Snippet:String) -> GMSMarker{
        let GmMarker = GMSMarker()
        GmMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(Latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(Longitude))
        GmMarker.title = Title
        GmMarker.snippet = Snippet
        GmMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "smallStoreIcon")
        return GmMarker
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`getDocument` is an [asynchronous task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean), so `numberOfMarkers` is only accessible *before* the closing `}`.

Do whatever you want with `numberOfMarkers` inside the `getDocument` listener, you may need to refactor your existing code to accommodate this. For example:

```
docRef = Firestore.firestore().document("Markol/Markers")
docRef.getDocument{ (docSnapshot, error) in
    guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else {return}
    let myData = docSnapshot.data()
    let numberOfMarkers = myData?["NumberofMarkers"] as? Int ?? 0
    processMarkers(numberOfMarkers, myData)
}
```

If this approach isn't clear, try posting more of your code in your question so others can help you restructure.

Comment: there is a way to set a new var out side of the {} and use it same as numberOfMarkers? and what the last line do?

Comment: I suggest you read the link I sent. Basically anything *outside* the `getDocument{}` cannot read values from inside it. If you post more code we can help you restructure it.

Comment: @OfekG In your original question please!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Variable/constant is always visible just inside scope where is declared, between curly braces `{...}`.

---

What you probably want to do is to get this value to return it or use somewhere else. Don't do it, since getting data from `Firestore` is asynchronus task, use completion handler instead and return value (or `nil` if you don’t have value) as completion's parameter when you have it

```
func call(completion: @escaping (Int?) -> Void) {
    ...
    docRef.getDocument{ docSnapshot, error in
        guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else {
            completion(nil)
            return 
        }
        let myData = docSnapshot.data()
        let numberOfMarkers = myData?["NumberofMarkers"] as? Int
        completion(numberOfMarkers)
    }
}
```

then when you need to call it

```
call { numberOfMarkers in // code inside this closure is called with parameter of type `Int?` when you receive data and call completion from inside `call`
    if let number = numberOfMarkers {
        ... // do something with it
    }
}
```

... here you can use it for next purpose